# Error running query: "Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Until the other day I was able to execute a BQ query, but now I get an error when I execute it:

> "Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region"

How can I run the query again?
What is causing me to run a query?

[image]

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please use the BigQuery issue tracker. Make sure to add your project id for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My BigQuery project id is `rmp-dmg`. For example, the job ID of the failed query is rmp-dmg: asia-northeast1.bquxjob_ee60761_16d4211ad60.

Comment: Please use the BigQuery issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: I posted on Issue Tracker.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could be a multitude of issues.

1. By reservation the system means computing slots. Either the sales team just made a configuration and it needs to be made aware across your organization.
2. You are using the computation in one region but the reservation is made for another. Eg: you made a EU reservation but still using the US zone to run your queries.
3. The connector/api/library might have a bug, and doesn't set the location wrapper correctly as indicated by you to use the correct reservation region.

Comment: The query is running in the asia-northeast1 region and no reservations are set.So I think it's strange.